# Change equation align in latex with eqnarray

Tags: latex

I need to finish a paper but i need to fix the equations formatting of a linear programming model. I am using the environment eqnarray and i almost have it formatted the way my advisor asked. This is a sample of i got [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl9zU.png). I need to align the right side of the equations to the left while aligning the left side to the right (the left side is OK). Does anyone know if there is a way to make this modification with the eqnarray environment?

This is part of the latex code that generated this image:

```latex
\begin{eqnarray}
        \mbox{s. t.} \qquad \sum_{j \in V_{+1} | i \neq j} x_{ij} \quad = & 1 & \forall\, i \in C \label{eq2} \\
        \sum_{j \in V_{+1} | i \neq j} x_{ij} \quad \leq & 1 & \forall\, i \in \{R \cup S\}  \label{eq3} \\
        \sum_{i \in V_{+1} | i \neq j} x_{ji} \quad = & \sum_{i \in V_{0} | i \neq j} x_{ij} & \forall\, j \in V  \label{eq4} \\
        \sum_{i \in \{C \cup R\}} y_{i} \quad \leq & O & \forall i \in R \label{eq27} \\
        \sum_{j \in V_{0} | i \neq j} x_{ji} \quad \leq & M \cdot y_{i} & \forall i \in R \label{eq7} \\ 
        \sum_{j \in V_{0} | h \neq j} x_{jh} \quad \leq & M \cdot y_{i} & \forall i \in R, h \in SK_{i} \label{eq8} \\ 
        t_{j} \quad \geq & t_{i} + ( td_{ij} + s_{i} ) \cdot x_{ij} - M \cdot (1 - x_{ij}) & \forall i \in C_{0}, j \in V_{1} | i \neq j \label{eq9} \\ 
        t_{j} \quad \geq & t_{i} + td_{ij} \cdot x_{ij} + ct \cdot x_{ij} - M \cdot (1 - x_{ij}) & \forall i \in \{R \cup SK_{h \in R}\}, j \in V_{1} | i \neq j \label{eq11}
\begin{eqnarray}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eqnarray` environment will not compatible for multi column align for multiple equation. So i am using `alignat` enviornment.

```
\begin{alignat}{3}
        \mbox{s. t.} \qquad \sum_{j \in V_{+1} | i \neq j} x_{ij} &= 1 &&\quad \forall\, i \in C\label{eq2} \\
        \sum_{j \in V_{+1} | i \neq j} x_{ij} &\leq 1 &&\quad \forall\, i \in \{R \cup S\}  \label{eq3} \\
        \sum_{i \in V_{+1} | i \neq j} x_{ji} & =\sum_{i \in V_{0} | i \neq j} x_{ij} &&\quad \forall\, j \in V  \label{eq4} \\
        \sum_{i \in \{C \cup R\}} y_{i} &\leq O &&\quad \forall i \in R \label{eq27} \\
        \sum_{j \in V_{0} | i \neq j} x_{ji} & \leq M \cdot y_{i} &&\quad \forall i \in R \label{eq7} \\
        \sum_{j \in V_{0} | h \neq j} x_{jh} &\leq M \cdot y_{i} &&\quad \forall i \in R, h \in SK_{i} \label{eq8} \\
        t_{j} &\geq t_{i} + ( td_{ij} + s_{i} ) \cdot x_{ij}\nonumber\\
         &\quad{} - M \cdot (1 - x_{ij}) &&\quad \forall i \in C_{0}, j \in V_{1} | i \neq j \label{eq9} \\
        t_{j} &\geq t_{i} + td_{ij} \cdot x_{ij} + ct \cdot x_{ij}\nonumber\\
         &\quad{}- M \cdot (1 - x_{ij}) &&\quad \forall i \in \{R \cup SK_{h \in R}\}, j \in V_{1} | i \neq j \label{eq11}
\end{alignat}
```

I think you got this!